# using cin in other headers C++

Tags: c++, header, cin

I want to get three variable from the user by using  in my own header ...

here's the piece of the code i have written ...

```
<class T>
Sparse<T>::Sparse(){

    std::cout << "Please Enter The Following Information" << std::endl << "Row:" ;
    std::cin >> this->rows;
    std::cout << "Column:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> this->column;
    std::cout << "Please Enter The Number of TermS:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> this->term;

}
```

i used forward decelaration for  in my own header :

```
  class cin;
```

the problem i've encountered is as you can see there is no loop for the function of the class But ...

when i run the code, the compiler runs this block multi_Times ...
Like the cin just can't initialize the variable ...

Like this

```
  "Please Enter The Following Information"
  "Rows:"
  "Columns:"
  "Please Enter The Number of TermS:"
  "Please Enter The Following Information"
  "Rows:"
  "Columns:"
  "Please Enter The Number of TermS:"
```

Please Help .....

Extra Detail ....

As Mr.Coffin Said I Want to use "Forward declaration" Please Help ME ...
How do i must use  ... 
cause including a header in another header is such a bad style to use ...

And yes i have two constructor one gets the argument for the  
the other works this way .... 
and it is because i dont want to have cin and cout and lots of equalation (=) in my main ... 
Thanks Mr.Coffin ....

Comment: Can you show a short complete example?

Comment: I suspect the constructor is being called another time. Can you show us the code ? And `cin` is not a class. It's an object of the standard input stream.

Comment: Why not `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: If you want a forward declaration of the ios stuff, don't try to do it yourself. The standard includes the `<iosfwd>` header for exactly this purpose; use it.

Comment: And it's better design to pass `rows`, `column` and `term` to the constructor

Comment: Why are you using a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of a class is there for the initial creation of the object. In this example, this is the *default* constructor. In general you probably don't want to write user-facing questions in the constructor of a class, let alone the default constructor.

Writing it your way means that any time you create an uninitialized Sparse, the user will be asked these questions.

```
Sparse<int> a, b;
```

This calls the constructor twice, asking the questions twice, forcing the user to answer the questions without knowing which 'Sparse' they are being questioned over.

```
Sparse<int> a, b;

if (day == "Monday") {
    a.something();
} else {
    b = a;
}
```

Here the user is prompted with questions that only make sense one day of the week.

But you also run into problems like:

```
std::vector<Sparse<int>> manySparses;
manySparses.resize(1000);
```

The user is now going to be asked the questions ... 1000 times.

Choose one of two approaches: Ask the questions BEFORE you construct the object; or choose sensible default values - e.g. values that indicate "I don't have values yet" and then populate the values after construction,

You could have a static member for asking the question or you could have a member that asks them after the object is constructed:

```
Sparse<int> a, b;
a.GetConstraints();
if (day == "Monday")
    b.GetConstraints();
else
    b = a;
```

But don't write a default constructor that asks the user questions like this.

---- Edit, regarding 'cin' ----

'cin' is not a class. It's an object. For portability, and just down right good practice, you shouldn't go injecting your own attempt to declare standard library types/structs/functions like this, especially not in headers.

Instead, accept it as a dependency and

```
#include <iostream>
```

in your header file before you try to use it.

---- Edit: final notes ----

When you think of "Construction" in the programming sense try to think on the scale of "deciding I'm going to build a skyscraper" rather than "undertaking the work of building the empire state building, selling space on the 101st floor and hiring a management team".

It's not that you can't/shouldn't write complex constructors, but your goal should simply be to get the object into a reliable state for the program.

```
class string {
public:
    string() {
        std::cout << "Enter the string you want: ";
        std::cin >> m_string;
        m_length = strlen(m_string);
    }
    ...
};
```

vs

```
class string {
public:
    string() : m_string(NULL), m_length(0) {}
    ...
};
```

Secondly, having a constructor which talks to standard input/output fundamentally cripples its usefulness. There's no problem with using that logic to obtain the values from the user, but if you put it into the class's constructor then the class can *only* be used in an application that has standard input/output (neither gui nor headless apps need apply).

Thirdly, how will you handle errors? What if cin gets closed after the first question? Your code doesn't check for it, and if it did, it would have to pass the burden to whomever is creating the object. Nobody expects to have to write

```
try {
    Object myObject; // may fail if user types 'wibble' instead of '13'.
} catch (wibble_input_as_columns_exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "Damnit, Dave, 'wibble' is not a valid number of columns." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer for all things except answering the glaring question of `class cin`, which was really the question.

Comment: That's a pretty fair point, editing.

Comment: He doesn't appear to be actually asking about that, his question says "the problem i've encountered is as you can see there is no loop for the function of the class But ...". So you're right, he needs to not have the "class cin;" declaration, it's wrong, but if he does it properly he shouldn't need it, either.

Comment: That is true, in this situation op doesn't/shouldn't need it but it still stands "Like the cin just can't initialize the variable ..." speaking to it repeating, like op *thinks* they want, but "cin" doesn't work which is easily answered by; "no, `#include <iostream>`. That's all :)

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I put - the edit didn't show up immediately for me tho, maybe SO is having some problems.